# Is there a non abelian group of order 759?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

I tried to use Sylow theorems to prove that there is not, but it is not trivial.

Comment: It may not be trivial, but it is not too hard!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$759 = 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 23$$

Show that there exists a non-commutative group of order $11 \cdot 23$.

${\bf Added:}$ Let's construct a non-commutative group $G$ of order $23\cdot 11$ as follows: the elements of $G$ are pairs 
$(a, m)$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}/23$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}/11$ and the multiplication is 
$$(a_1, m_1) \cdot (a_2, m_2) = ( a_1 + 2^{m_1}\cdot  a_2\ ,\  m_1 + m_2)$$
where we use the fact that $2^{11} \equiv 1 \mod 23$.

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct is to approach this problem through representation theory, and a process of elimination to show such a group cannot exist. These facts may prove useful

(1) The prime factorisation is $759 = 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 23$.

(1.5) Look at how few factors there are!

(2) Each conjugacy class is a normal subgroup, and every normal subgroup is a union of conjugacy classes. If the group is non-Abelian, some conjugacy class has more than one element. Since $759$ has only three factors, the order has only about six possibilities. Can you make a short list of what the conjugacy classes could look like?

(3) The group has as many conjugacy classes as it has **irreducible representations**.

Exactly what (3) means is probably not needed. The useful fact is that, if there were three **irreducible representations** say $\rho_1, \rho_2, \rho_3$, then each has a positive integer $d_i$ called its **degree** such that $d_1^2 + d_2^2 + d_3^2 = |G| = 759$.

But maybe we cannot express $759$ as a sum of exactly three cubes. This would prevent there being exactly three conjugacy classes. Perhaps a similar argument can be used for each other possibility vis-a-vie the conjugacy class layout.

Answer (score 0):

A number $n$ has the property that every group of order $n$ is abelian (in this case we call the number an abelian number), if $n$ is cubefree and there is no prime power $p^k$ dividing $n$ and a prime $q$ dividing $n$ with $q|p^k-1$.

Here this is not the case because of $11|23-1$, so $759$ is not abelian, so there must be a non-abelian group with order $759$. There are $2$ groups of order $759$ , $1$ is abelian and $1$ is non-abelian.

Comment: Could you please reference to appropriate results? I believe it is enough to show that there is more than one (up to isomorphism) group of order $759$ since any abelian group of that order should be $\mathbb Z_3\oplus\mathbb Z_{11}\oplus \mathbb Z_{23}\cong \mathbb Z_{759}$, but why should there be exactly two of them? I suspect the other one is $\mathbb Z_3\times(\mathbb Z_{23}\rtimes_\varphi\mathbb Z_{11})$ where $\varphi$ is given by composition $\mathbb Z_{11} \to \mathbb Z_{22} \to (\mathbb Z_{23})^\times \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_{23})$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the order of $G$ be 759. It is not difficult to see that the 23-Sylow subgroup is normal in $G$. Let $a$ generate the 23-Sylow subgroup in $G$. Now suppose $b\ne1$ in $G$ is such that order of $b$ is 33. If the commutation $ab=ba^2$ is assumed, then the group generated by $a$ and $b$ is of order $759$.

Comment: Can you construct a Cayley table for the group you created, or some kind of matrix representation? It would be nice to give a full table representation of it.

Comment: Constructing a full Cayley Table or a representation sounds tedious for such a large group. However, one could write out the product of any two general elements in the described group. From the commutation relation, it is obvious that any element of the group can be written as $a^tb^s$. Consider now the product of two such elements, then $a^sb^ta^{s'}b^{t'}=a^{s+2^ts'}b^{t+t'}$.